# Error using Picker / body-parser npm package in Meteor

Tags: meteor, body-parser

Trying to run this code on Meteor server side, cannot figure out a way to begin debugging this...I didn't think I need to have a lib folder for this?

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { Picker } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker';

Picker.middleware(bodyParser.json());
```

Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/types/json'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the whole error text with stacktrace?

Comment: Most likely an npm issue. Can you provide the contents of your package.json? Also, best first try might be clearing your node_modules folder and reinstalling all npm modules with "meteor npm install"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install picker by **atmosphere**

```
meteor add meteorhacks:picker
```

To check if everything is ok execute

```
grep meteorhacks:picker .meteor/packages
```

Second package should be installed from **npm repository**

```
yarn add body-parser
```

To check if everything is ok execute

```
grep body-parser package.json
```

If problem is still not solved you can simple "clear cache"

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn
```

But honestly I suggest use express rather than picker, because it seems to be abandoned. Tutorial about integrating express with meteor:

> http://www.mhurwi.com/meteor-with-express/

Comment: thanks, agree, decided to stay away from atmosphere packages mostly. Express is a good idea. For my issue in that moment I think I just used straight up XMLHttpRequest, which worked fine for one-off tasks.